# How to definitely switch off the Check Spelling function

Tags: spellchecker

I formulated the question entirely enough in the title. Below I give some background to explain why do I need to do such a crazy thing.

I have a son of 17 years old who has autistic problems. It is hard enough by itself. A  part of this problem is that he cannot write fast enough. He can neither keep up with his school mates nor fulfill his tests during the school hour. On the keyboard, however, he types fast enough.

I agreed with his teachers that he will visit the lessons and tests with his laptop. It is understood that he will have an editor.  This one should be convenient to type both texts as well as mathematical formulae for the lessons in Mathematics. The teachers have nothing against that.

However, they warned me that in 1 year my son has to pass exams. Such an editor can also be allowed for the exams. However, it will only be accepted, provided the function of the Check Spelling is definitely switched off. It means that it will be impossible ever to switch it on. My son must be unable to switch it on during the exam, check the spelling, and then again switch it off.

In my experience, the editor that one obtains with Mathematica is very convenient and fast to type, if one remembers the hotkeys. Since he already uses Mathematica, I would like him to use this editor.

This is the reason to ask you if you have an idea of how to definitely switch the Check Spelling off?

Comment: Do you mean "A part of this problem is that he cannot write *by hand* fast enough"?  Also I don't understand what you mean by "redactor".

Comment: What he means is `CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, ShowAutoSpellCheck]`.Or, setting in Preferences / Interface the checkbox "Check spelling as you type"

Comment: @QuantumDot  1. Yes, I mean that he writes by hand very slowly, and it can never be improved. 2. I am sorry, I had in mind to write the word "editor", but by foolishness used instead a Russian analog "redactor". I corrected now.

Comment: @QuantumDot "Also I don't understand what you mean by 'redactor'." -- Alexei misspelled "redaktor". (I hope it is all clearer now...)

Answer (score 6):

Deleting or renaming this folder (without Mathematica being started)

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", 
  "SpellingData"}]
```

will switch off the "Check spelling as you type", no matter what `CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, ShowAutoSpellCheck]` or the checkbox in Preferences is set.

Comment: Thank you. Do I understand correctly, that it is not only the function "Check spelling as you type" will be switched off in this case, but any Spell Checking? Since it is this function that I need to switch off.

Comment: I think so. But you can ask Wolfram Support for more information.